# How can I avoid recompiling code that hasn't changed?

Tags: visual-c++, msbuild

My workplace uses SVN and I use Git locally. My workflow involves updating from SVN, committing to an "svn_only" Git branch, then rebasing my current topic branch on that.

All of which is to say that the "modified" timestamps on my source files change fairly frequently, even though the contents hasn't actually changed. This can result in very long compile times as the program decides it needs to build stuff that actually does have up-to-date object and library files built.

I've written a script that goes through my project and updates the "modified" timestamp on every single .lib, .exe, .lastbuildstate, .ilk, .pdb, .o and .tlog file, to the time when I started the script. However, this doesn't have any effect on what it decides needs to be built.

I've read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/incremental-builds, which states

> An item is considered up-to-date if its output file is the same age or newer than its input file or files.
>
> If all output items are up-to-date, MSBuild skips the target. This incremental build of the target can significantly improve the build speed. If only some files are up-to-date, MSBuild executes the target but skips the up-to-date items, and thereby brings all items up-to-date.

So... that should do it, shouldn't it? What am I missing? Does it need to be the "Created" timestamp as well as the "Modified" one?

e: here's my current attempt. It doesn't have the desired effect, but I don't know why:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z $1 ];then
  echo "Usage: $0 <commit hash> [<to commit hash (else head)>]"
  exit 1
fi

commit1=$1
commit2=$2

timestamp=`date --date yesterday +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S` #201807051536.54

git diff $commit1 $commit2 --name-only |  xargs --verbose -d '\n' touch -t$timestamp
```

This does indeed modify the target files to yesterday's timestamp, but that only partially affects whether or not MSVC decides they need to be rebuilt.

With everything up-to-date (recently built), if I `touch` a source file to set its timestamp to yesterday MSVC doesn't compile that. Cool. If I simply `touch` it to set the timestamp to current time, it *does* compile it. So the timestamp of the source file is evidently one factor, but it can't be the only factor.

Comment: Set modified timestamp earlier than e.g. timestamp of output executable?

Comment: You mean get the timestamp on the output executable, then set the timestamp on every source file to be a bit earlier than that? That's not ideal as there are thousands and thousands of source files. I can give it a try, though.

Comment: It's really not great. I'm trying `find source \( -name '*.h' -or -name '*.hpp' -or -name '*.c' -or -name '*.cpp' -or -name '*.cxx' \) -not -path ".svn"  | xargs -d '\n' -n 1 -P $WORKER_PROCESSES touch -t$timestamp` with 16 and then 32 processes, and setting the timestamp to yesterday. It takes 15 minutes to run, for around 29,000 source files.

This does work in that it prevents the files being recompiled, but is very very slow. There should be far fewer target files, so that should be faster.

Comment: (To clarify, that's bash script. I'm using Git's install of bash for Windows. But either way there are so many more source files than output files, so running this on the source files isn't the best option)

Comment: Should have been more clear: only set the modified date of the files which actually have timestamps newer than the output, i.e. the ones which have been changed by the rebase process; I assume it's possible to get a list of those files during the rebasing somehow, didn't check.

Comment: Can you publish the script? I'd be curious to read it

Comment: @sudo rm -rf slash I don't really have a working one. At present I'm using `timestamp=`date --date yesterday +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S` #201807051536.54

git diff $commit1 $commit2 --name-only |  xargs --verbose -d '\n' touch -t$timestamp`

It doesn't seem to have the desired effect, though, as the files in question are still compiled.